# the scope of arguments declared in functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, arguments

A question about scope which I couldn't find online.
If you would have a piece of code like:

```
Function foo(myVar) {
return myVar + 1
}
```

Would *myVar* be bounded to the scope of foo?
Thank you for your time.

Edit:
this is different from a question about scopes of variables in arguments because I wasn't sure if that would apply to arguments, since they weren't stated with `var` before them.

Comment: @VisioN I'm sure this is a duplicate, but that linked question doesn't have much to say about the distinctions between function parameters and local variables.

Comment: function parameters are *essentially* the same as local variables as far as scope goes. Not exactly the same, but mostly you can think about them as equivalent.

Comment: Where? I couldn't find it. I will look again though

Comment: @Pointy The linked question provides the central idea: there are a global scope and a local scope. Everything that is defined within a function, including functional arguments, is defined in the local scope of this function. There is no detailed explanation of the difference between parameters and local variables, but scope-wise they behave the same.

Comment: @VisioN oh I agree; I just was noting that mention of the similarity between parameters and locals is either not mentioned, or buried somewhere in the rest of the information there. The comment I added above should help this OP I hope :)

Comment: @Pointy Yup! That's why I have upvoted it ;)

Comment: It helped me a lot. thank you Pointy Yup! and VisioN